# When was TLSv1.2 ciphers were added as a default selection while using python's openssl module

Tags: python-2.7, tls1.2, pyopenssl

I want to know when exactly was it added that the default cipher selection would be TLSv1.2 ciphers while using the wrapper function of python's openssl.

I was able to find this data in the changelog of openssl. It seems that even though TLSv1.2 support was added on 14th March, 2012, it was made a default option only on 25th August, 2016.

Changes between 1.0.0h and 1.0.1  [14 Mar 2012]

> *) Initial TLS v1.2 support. Add new SHA256 digest to ssl code, switch
>        to SHA256 for PRF when using TLS v1.2 and later. Add new SHA256 based
>        ciphersuites. At present only RSA key exchange ciphersuites work with
>        TLS v1.2. Add new option for TLS v1.2 replacing the old and obsolete
>        SSL_OP_PKCS1_CHECK flags with SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2. New TLSv1.2 methods
>        and version checking.

Changes between 1.0.2h and 1.1.0  [25 Aug 2016]

> *) Changes to the DEFAULT cipherlist:
>          - Prefer (EC)DHE handshakes over plain RSA.
>          - Prefer AEAD ciphers over legacy ciphers.
>          - Prefer ECDSA over RSA when both certificates are available.
>          - Prefer TLSv1.2 ciphers/PRF.                                    <---
>          - Remove DSS, SEED, IDEA, CAMELLIA, and AES-CCM from the
>            default cipherlist.
>        [Emilia Käsper]
>        [Steve Henson]

But this is for the openssl library.

For pyopenssl, the changelog seems less detailed, there is an update and version release (version 16.1.0) just after a day (on 26th August, 2016), but they have not mentioned this detail. And I am not able to find a mention of which exact version of openssl is the pyopenssl using in the changelog history.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking at the date, you can say [25 Aug 2016] since openssl v1.1.0 is released as you mentioned.

This is not a problem with the version of `pyopenssl`, but rather with the version of the `openssl` library you are using. Since `pyopenssl`, a wrapper library of `openssl` for python, doesn't modify `openssl` itself. so, if you are using openssl v1.1.0 or later, TLS v1.2 is the default, otherwise TLS v1.2 is not the default.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  You will not "find a mention of which exact version of openssl is the pyopenssl using" because it wraps whatever openssl is available for the system to use.  The version you have installed is the version that will be used.